# Data queued in socket input buffer upon force disconnect

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, gtk

Two completely different computers, one running Windows 7 ultimate and one running Windows Server run the very same program. That program establishes a P2P network architecture between them, using GSocket, which inclines that the underlying socket types are platform-specific hence windows `SOCKET`.

a `select()`-like function is used as a form of detection for when there is data in the input queue and it works flawlessly. When the Windows 7 client disconnects forcefully, nothing happens, the `select()`-like function timeouts, which is the expected behavior (as it can only return canceled or timeout error and `TRUE`/`FALSE` return value)

But if the Windows server peer disconnects the same way, it causes the `select()`-like function to return that there is data in the input queue, which in turn invokes a `recv()`, which fails with `(-1)`. In that case `g_socket_get_available_bytes(socket)` returns `0` as there are no bytes, which explains the `recv()` failing.

Now this is not an issue between client/server, because the same thing happens if I swap computers such that the other computer is the one connecting.
And I cannot know how this is platform-specific problem when both computers are Windows and both run the same GTK+ version runtimes.

---

What could be causing this awfully undesired behavior?
Is it possible that the `select()`-like function behavior (`g_socket_condition_timed_wait()`) differs across Windows distributions that much.

---

Essentially the problem is fixed by replacing
`g_socket_condition_timed_wait(socket, G_IO_IN, 32 * MS_SECOND, NULL, NULL);`
with

```
gboolean cnp_receive_wait_for_available_bytes (GSocket* socket/*, gint64 timeout*/)
{
    return (g_socket_get_available_bytes(socket) > 0);
}
```

in which case the check isn't passed upon force disconnect, but to be honest I prefer the other way around, if upon forceful disconnect, `g_socket_condition_timed_wait` returns `TRUE` and causes the `recv` to fail, so that I don't need to do any sort of additional pinging to detect that the peer has disconnected forcefully.

---

**Update** It is not `g_socket_condition_timed_wait()`s fault, I just found out that

```
gboolean cnp_send_failed (GSocket* socket)
{ /* Probably unspecified how recv() and send() tolerates a zero-length message. */
    return(g_socket_send_with_blocking(socket, "", 0, TRUE, NULL, NULL) == (-1));
}
```

similarly to the `g_socket_condition_timed_wait()` fails only for the Windows 7 computer if the windows server peer disconnects, which only makes the problem worse as it makes me unable to detect that the windows server computer disconnects forcefully with the function above. I don't know if OS properly handles closing the input/output channels.